# Textract JSON data to Image drawing with Kendo UI Angular 11

Tags: html, angular, canvas, text-extraction, kendo-angular-ui

I have a JSON object which was extracted from an Image using [AWS Textract](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/) after that I'm trying to draw same image using this textract data.

I'm trying to use [Kendo Angular Drawing](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/drawing/) API for this and with limited documentation and usage examples I'm not completely sure about how to implement this from the geometry values in the JSON

Sample extracted object

```json
    {
      "BlockType": "WORD",
      "Confidence": 99.93840789794922,
      "Text": "The",
      "TextType": "PRINTED",
      "Geometry": {
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.036412131041288376,
          "Height": 0.014151308685541153,
          "Left": 0.13431107997894287,
          "Top": 0.03131059184670448
        },
        "Polygon": [
          {
            "X": 0.13431107997894287,
            "Y": 0.03131059184670448
          },
          {
            "X": 0.17072321474552155,
            "Y": 0.03131059184670448
          },
          {
            "X": 0.17072321474552155,
            "Y": 0.045461900532245636
          },
          {
            "X": 0.13431107997894287,
            "Y": 0.045461900532245636
          }
        ]
      },
      "Id": "da6d85a6-3c79-484b-a07d-d84e968844ae",
      "Page": 1,
      "SearchKey": "The"
    },
    {
      "BlockType": "WORD",
      "Confidence": 99.77457427978516,
      "Text": "Standard",
      "TextType": "PRINTED",
      "Geometry": {
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.08427372574806213,
          "Height": 0.013822372071444988,
          "Left": 0.17733719944953918,
          "Top": 0.03183155879378319
        },
        "Polygon": [
          {
            "X": 0.17733719944953918,
            "Y": 0.03183155879378319
          },
          {
            "X": 0.2616109251976013,
            "Y": 0.03183155879378319
          },
          {
            "X": 0.2616109251976013,
            "Y": 0.04565393179655075
          },
          {
            "X": 0.17733719944953918,
            "Y": 0.04565393179655075
          }
        ]
      },
      "Id": "e6587cca-2e7e-4231-9978-4b303241645b",
      "Page": 1,
      "SearchKey": "Standard"
    },
    {
      "BlockType": "WORD",
      "Confidence": 99.82964324951172,
      "Text": "Bill",
      "TextType": "PRINTED",
      "Geometry": {
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.035674601793289185,
          "Height": 0.014618489891290665,
          "Left": 0.26750874519348145,
          "Top": 0.03160806745290756
        },
        "Polygon": [
          {
            "X": 0.26750874519348145,
            "Y": 0.03160806745290756
          },
          {
            "X": 0.30318334698677063,
            "Y": 0.03160806745290756
          },
          {
            "X": 0.30318334698677063,
            "Y": 0.04622655734419823
          },
          {
            "X": 0.26750874519348145,
            "Y": 0.04622655734419823
          }
        ]
      },
      "Id": "a6947531-ae08-40b3-8161-8fa78d430ad4",
      "Page": 1,
      "SearchKey": "Bill"
    },
    {
      "BlockType": "WORD",
      "Confidence": 99.97029876708984,
      "Text": "of",
      "TextType": "PRINTED",
      "Geometry": {
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.022517522796988487,
          "Height": 0.014790677465498447,
          "Left": 0.3098187744617462,
          "Top": 0.03196505829691887
        },
        "Polygon": [
          {
            "X": 0.3098187744617462,
            "Y": 0.03196505829691887
          },
          {
            "X": 0.33233630657196045,
            "Y": 0.03196505829691887
          },
          {
            "X": 0.33233630657196045,
            "Y": 0.04675573855638504
          },
          {
            "X": 0.3098187744617462,
            "Y": 0.04675573855638504
          }
        ]
      },
      "Id": "53853140-e3c4-4f3a-a4b7-67ad39e1bb32",
      "Page": 1,
      "SearchKey": "of"
    },
    {
      "BlockType": "WORD",
      "Confidence": 99.88966369628906,
      "Text": "Lading",
      "TextType": "PRINTED",
      "Geometry": {
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.06747607886791229,
          "Height": 0.01772529073059559,
          "Left": 0.3355117440223694,
          "Top": 0.032798975706100464
        },
        "Polygon": [
          {
            "X": 0.3355117440223694,
            "Y": 0.032798975706100464
          },
          {
            "X": 0.40298783779144287,
            "Y": 0.032798975706100464
          },
          {
            "X": 0.40298783779144287,
            "Y": 0.0505242682993412
          },
          {
            "X": 0.3355117440223694,
            "Y": 0.0505242682993412
          }
        ]
      },
      "Id": "5060d908-2318-48ad-bd6c-e4694501a8ce",
      "Page": 1,
      "SearchKey": "Lading"
    },
    {
      "BlockType": "WORD",
      "Confidence": 99.94490814208984,
      "Text": "Form",
      "TextType": "PRINTED",
      "Geometry": {
        "BoundingBox": {
          "Width": 0.051753073930740356,
          "Height": 0.014337458647787571,
          "Left": 0.4095679521560669,
          "Top": 0.033189330250024796
        },
        "Polygon": [
          {
            "X": 0.4095679521560669,
            "Y": 0.033189330250024796
          },
          {
            "X": 0.46132102608680725,
            "Y": 0.033189330250024796
          },
          {
            "X": 0.46132102608680725,
            "Y": 0.04752678796648979
          },
          {
            "X": 0.4095679521560669,
            "Y": 0.04752678796648979
          }
        ]
      },
      "Id": "3cf3fb15-e77f-48a5-bf76-be35d32f8be6",
      "Page": 1,
      "SearchKey": "Form"
    },
```

Canvas drawing is completely new to me and I'm little lost about this implementation

Any recommendations will help me thanks

Comment: Unless you have found a plugin that converts this specific JSON format for you, it looks like you are going to have to create a function that converts the JSON objects to kendo Text objects, scaling the points as you do so, and then draw them to a surface. Which part are you having a problem with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The retrieved data from AWS Textract are not exactly images.

The simplest way to say it is that they are blocks of recognized text, as stated [at their webpage](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/):

> Amazon Textract makes it easy to add document text detection and
> analysis to your applications. The Amazon Textract Text Detection API
> can detect typed and handwritten text in a variety of documents
> including financial reports, medical records, and tax forms. For
> documents with structured data, you can use the Amazon Textract
> Document Analysis API to extract text, forms and tables. Furthermore,
> if you would like to process invoices and receipts, you can use the
> AnalyzeExpense API.

Those blocks are the results of the text-detection operation. A Block represents items that are recognized in a document within a group of pixels close to each other ([see more here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/textract/latest/dg/API_Block.html)). They only represent something for the input you've sent to the API.

I've made the following snippet which does what you ask. However, the gathered response from the API is meant to be used as your implementation needs; and may not be the following way:

```js
var data = [{
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.93840789794922,
          "Text": "The",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.036412131041288376,
              "Height": 0.014151308685541153,
              "Left": 0.13431107997894287,
              "Top": 0.03131059184670448
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.13431107997894287,
                "Y": 0.03131059184670448
              },
              {
                "X": 0.17072321474552155,
                "Y": 0.03131059184670448
              },
              {
                "X": 0.17072321474552155,
                "Y": 0.045461900532245636
              },
              {
                "X": 0.13431107997894287,
                "Y": 0.045461900532245636
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "da6d85a6-3c79-484b-a07d-d84e968844ae",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "The"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.77457427978516,
          "Text": "Standard",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.08427372574806213,
              "Height": 0.013822372071444988,
              "Left": 0.17733719944953918,
              "Top": 0.03183155879378319
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.17733719944953918,
                "Y": 0.03183155879378319
              },
              {
                "X": 0.2616109251976013,
                "Y": 0.03183155879378319
              },
              {
                "X": 0.2616109251976013,
                "Y": 0.04565393179655075
              },
              {
                "X": 0.17733719944953918,
                "Y": 0.04565393179655075
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "e6587cca-2e7e-4231-9978-4b303241645b",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "Standard"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.82964324951172,
          "Text": "Bill",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.035674601793289185,
              "Height": 0.014618489891290665,
              "Left": 0.26750874519348145,
              "Top": 0.03160806745290756
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.26750874519348145,
                "Y": 0.03160806745290756
              },
              {
                "X": 0.30318334698677063,
                "Y": 0.03160806745290756
              },
              {
                "X": 0.30318334698677063,
                "Y": 0.04622655734419823
              },
              {
                "X": 0.26750874519348145,
                "Y": 0.04622655734419823
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "a6947531-ae08-40b3-8161-8fa78d430ad4",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "Bill"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.97029876708984,
          "Text": "of",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.022517522796988487,
              "Height": 0.014790677465498447,
              "Left": 0.3098187744617462,
              "Top": 0.03196505829691887
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.3098187744617462,
                "Y": 0.03196505829691887
              },
              {
                "X": 0.33233630657196045,
                "Y": 0.03196505829691887
              },
              {
                "X": 0.33233630657196045,
                "Y": 0.04675573855638504
              },
              {
                "X": 0.3098187744617462,
                "Y": 0.04675573855638504
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "53853140-e3c4-4f3a-a4b7-67ad39e1bb32",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "of"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.88966369628906,
          "Text": "Lading",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.06747607886791229,
              "Height": 0.01772529073059559,
              "Left": 0.3355117440223694,
              "Top": 0.032798975706100464
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.3355117440223694,
                "Y": 0.032798975706100464
              },
              {
                "X": 0.40298783779144287,
                "Y": 0.032798975706100464
              },
              {
                "X": 0.40298783779144287,
                "Y": 0.0505242682993412
              },
              {
                "X": 0.3355117440223694,
                "Y": 0.0505242682993412
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "5060d908-2318-48ad-bd6c-e4694501a8ce",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "Lading"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.94490814208984,
          "Text": "Form",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.051753073930740356,
              "Height": 0.014337458647787571,
              "Left": 0.4095679521560669,
              "Top": 0.033189330250024796
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.4095679521560669,
                "Y": 0.033189330250024796
              },
              {
                "X": 0.46132102608680725,
                "Y": 0.033189330250024796
              },
              {
                "X": 0.46132102608680725,
                "Y": 0.04752678796648979
              },
              {
                "X": 0.4095679521560669,
                "Y": 0.04752678796648979
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "3cf3fb15-e77f-48a5-bf76-be35d32f8be6",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "Form"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.93840789794922,
          "Text": "The",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.036412131041288376,
              "Height": 0.014151308685541153,
              "Left": 0.13431107997894287,
              "Top": 0.03131059184670448
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.13431107997894287,
                "Y": 0.03131059184670448
              },
              {
                "X": 0.17072321474552155,
                "Y": 0.03131059184670448
              },
              {
                "X": 0.17072321474552155,
                "Y": 0.045461900532245636
              },
              {
                "X": 0.13431107997894287,
                "Y": 0.045461900532245636
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "da6d85a6-3c79-484b-a07d-d84e968844ae",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "The"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.77457427978516,
          "Text": "Standard",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.08427372574806213,
              "Height": 0.013822372071444988,
              "Left": 0.17733719944953918,
              "Top": 0.03183155879378319
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.17733719944953918,
                "Y": 0.03183155879378319
              },
              {
                "X": 0.2616109251976013,
                "Y": 0.03183155879378319
              },
              {
                "X": 0.2616109251976013,
                "Y": 0.04565393179655075
              },
              {
                "X": 0.17733719944953918,
                "Y": 0.04565393179655075
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "e6587cca-2e7e-4231-9978-4b303241645b",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "Standard"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.82964324951172,
          "Text": "Bill",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.035674601793289185,
              "Height": 0.014618489891290665,
              "Left": 0.26750874519348145,
              "Top": 0.03160806745290756
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.26750874519348145,
                "Y": 0.03160806745290756
              },
              {
                "X": 0.30318334698677063,
                "Y": 0.03160806745290756
              },
              {
                "X": 0.30318334698677063,
                "Y": 0.04622655734419823
              },
              {
                "X": 0.26750874519348145,
                "Y": 0.04622655734419823
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "a6947531-ae08-40b3-8161-8fa78d430ad4",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "Bill"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.97029876708984,
          "Text": "of",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.022517522796988487,
              "Height": 0.014790677465498447,
              "Left": 0.3098187744617462,
              "Top": 0.03196505829691887
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.3098187744617462,
                "Y": 0.03196505829691887
              },
              {
                "X": 0.33233630657196045,
                "Y": 0.03196505829691887
              },
              {
                "X": 0.33233630657196045,
                "Y": 0.04675573855638504
              },
              {
                "X": 0.3098187744617462,
                "Y": 0.04675573855638504
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "53853140-e3c4-4f3a-a4b7-67ad39e1bb32",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "of"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.88966369628906,
          "Text": "Lading",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.06747607886791229,
              "Height": 0.01772529073059559,
              "Left": 0.3355117440223694,
              "Top": 0.032798975706100464
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.3355117440223694,
                "Y": 0.032798975706100464
              },
              {
                "X": 0.40298783779144287,
                "Y": 0.032798975706100464
              },
              {
                "X": 0.40298783779144287,
                "Y": 0.0505242682993412
              },
              {
                "X": 0.3355117440223694,
                "Y": 0.0505242682993412
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "5060d908-2318-48ad-bd6c-e4694501a8ce",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "Lading"
        },
        {
          "BlockType": "WORD",
          "Confidence": 99.94490814208984,
          "Text": "Form",
          "TextType": "PRINTED",
          "Geometry": {
            "BoundingBox": {
              "Width": 0.051753073930740356,
              "Height": 0.014337458647787571,
              "Left": 0.4095679521560669,
              "Top": 0.033189330250024796
            },
            "Polygon": [
              {
                "X": 0.4095679521560669,
                "Y": 0.033189330250024796
              },
              {
                "X": 0.46132102608680725,
                "Y": 0.033189330250024796
              },
              {
                "X": 0.46132102608680725,
                "Y": 0.04752678796648979
              },
              {
                "X": 0.4095679521560669,
                "Y": 0.04752678796648979
              }
            ]
          },
          "Id": "3cf3fb15-e77f-48a5-bf76-be35d32f8be6",
          "Page": 1,
          "SearchKey": "Form"
        }
    ];

    const zoom = 1400;
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const drawer = {
      BoundingBox: drawBoundingBox,
      Polygon: drawPolygon,
    };
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000ff";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;

    data.forEach((args) => {
      if (args.Geometry) {
        for (var key in args.Geometry) {
          if (typeof drawer[key] === 'function') {
            drawer[key](args.Geometry[key], args.Text);
          } else {
            console.error('Unsupported object, you\'ll need to add support here!');
          }
        }
        
      }
    });

    function drawBoundingBox(args, text) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(args.Left * zoom, args.Top * zoom, args.Width * zoom, args.Height * zoom);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.font = (args.Height * zoom) + "px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(text, (args.Left * zoom), (args.Top * zoom) + (args.Height * zoom));
    }

    function drawPolygon(args, text) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(args[0].X * zoom, args[0].Y * zoom);          
      for (var i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        ctx.lineTo(args[i].X * zoom, args[i].Y * zoom);
      }
      ctx.lineTo(args[0].X * zoom, args[0].Y * zoom);
      ctx.stroke();
      
      const h = ((args[args.length - 1].Y - args[0].Y) * zoom);
      ctx.font = h + "px Arial";
      ctx.strokeText(text, args[0].X * zoom, (args[0].Y + h) * zoom);
    }
```

```html
<canvas width="850" height="450" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

##### Canvas Drawing

This is the output for the example JSON data you've provided by using the snippet code:
[image: Canvas Drawing Screenshot]

Canvas drawing is not that hard. To code the snippet I've shared to you, you only need knowledge on 3 subjects ([Text](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_text.asp), [Rect](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rect.asp) and [lineTo](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_lineto.asp))

---

##### Kendo Angular Drawing

I've ported the vanilla code to Kendo Angular Drawing in [this stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tjq9wj?file=app/draw-scene.ts), I'd like to let you know that vanilla is a lot easier to use than Kendo, this is the output:
[image: Kendo Angular Drawing Screenshot]

---

In both cases, canvas and kendo; I had to add a `zoom` variable because your `X, Y` values were too small.